# Python - multithreading + csv

Tags: python, csv, multithreading

Estou tentando escrever arquivos csv utilizando uma Thread para cada arquivo. O código itera uma lista gerada pelo groupby e chama uma thread para cada grupo.

Chamando a função diretamente os arquivos são salvos normalmente:

[save_csv(uf[0]+'.csv', header, uf[1]) for uf in ufs]

Utilizando Threads, os arquivos são salvos apenas com o cabeçalho, mesmo a funcão sendo executada até o fim

[threading.Thread(target=(save_csv), args=(uf[0]+'.csv', header, uf[1])).start()  for uf in ufs]

Função save_csv:

```py
def save_csv(file, header, content):
    with open(file, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter=';', fieldnames=header)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(list(map(vars, content)))
```

Existe algum motivo pra que isso ocorra?

Obs.: O código está utilizando orientação a objetos e threads por exigência da lista de exercícios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as variáveis "vars" e "content" são globais então serão acessadas em paralelo em todas as threads. 
Você não fala e nem mostra como são criadas, não tem como saber e nem dar a resposta correta.

Só é possível adiantar que como você não passa como parâmetro, todas as threads " vão enxergar o mesmo conteúdo da variável "contents". Se você usar "multiprocessing", sim, uma "foto" das estruturas de dados globais é tirada no momento em que um subprocesso é criado, e toma vida de forma independente. Com threads, todas as threads enxergam a mesma variável.

Comment: Esclareceu a dúvida, muito obrigado!